# Moq - cannot iterate through a hidden IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, mocking, moq

We have a reasonably complicated interface hierarchy and I'm struggling to get Moq to do what I want it to.

I have an interface `IReservation` which extends `IRulesReservation`, and hides its enumerator with a new implementation of another type.

```
public interface IReservation : IRulesReservation
{
    new IEnumerator<IRoutePart> GetEnumerator();
}
```

`IRulesReservation` extends `IEnumerable`.

```
public interface IRulesReservation : IEnumerable<IRulesRoutePart>
{
}
```

The method I'm trying to test takes in an `IReservation`, but at various points needs to access the `IEnumerable<IRulesRoutePart>`. My Mock is setup like so:

```
m_mock = new Mock<IReservation>();
m_mock.As<IRulesReservation>().Setup(r => r.GetEnumerator()).Returns(routeParts.Select(rp => (IRulesRoutePart)rp).GetEnumerator());
```

In the example, `routeParts` is a list of `IRouteParts` that come from `Mock<IRouteParts>` objects that are setup with `.As<IRulesRoutePart>()`.

Whenever I get to a bit of code in the function I'm testing that uses the enumerator, it steps over the iteration as though the collection was empty.

Am I doing something wrong in my setup? Or is Moq just unable to handle an enumerator that is hidden in this way?

---

**Edit:** some strange behaviour I've just noticed when running test code on the mock:

```
Assert.That((reservation.Object as IRulesReservation).Count() == 8);
Assert.That((reservation.Object as IEnumerable<IRulesRoutePart>).Count() == 8);
```

The first line will pass, but the second line will fail.
I tried changing the mock to specifically setup an enumerator for `IEnumerable<IRulesRoutePart>`, but to no effect:

```
m_mock.As<IEnumerable<IRulesRoutePart>>().Setup(r => r.GetEnumerator()).Returns(routeParts.Select(rp => (IRulesRoutePart)rp).GetEnumerator());
```

Comment: Have you found any other information out about this? I'm having the same problem and trying to figure a way around it.

Comment: @poindexter12 - I never managed to solve this problem, but we later found out that Moq will cache the enumerator that you get when you call into the mocked GetEnumerator() the first time. This means that subsequent calls will return the same enumerator, which may be why I was getting different behaviour on subsequent calls. To fix this you can mock GetEnumerator() to return an anonymous method that creates a new Enumerator, rather than calling directly into the concrete implementation of GetEnumerator() as in my sample code above. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Does the object that your setup returns actually have data? That's probably your problem.

Comment: it does, routeParts in the example is a list of IRouteParts that come from Mock<IRouteParts> that are setup .As<IRulesRoutePart>() as well.

Comment: Somewhere you have to populate the data to be returned by your setup. Where are you creating a populated list of irouteparts with fake data?

Comment: Not sure how it's relevant, but the list of IRouteParts is created beforehand and held in the variable called routeParts in that example.

Comment: If you inspect route parts before the setup call above does it have values? Is it only after the call the return is empty?

Comment: yep, setting a breakpoint on that line shows the list is populated. After the setup is finished and I call into the production code, the iteration will act as if it was empty.